# mamp php myadmin stored procedures not allows null as input

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have a problem with phpmyadmin in wamp.

The stored procedures doesn't allow null input values.

I always check the input value with if condition, so that I have a choice to select different operations :D. But it doesn't work.

The same project works in MAMP. But why not in WAMP. Thanks in advance. . . .

```
BEGIN         
    SELECT stdsubjectid, subj_name, subj_cr_dt, subj_display, subj_status FROM es_subjects;
END
```

NOTE: a_id is input type is BIGINT(20).

Actually I didn't use it once it raises an error.

So If I passed an empty a_id, it doesn't show anything.

If I pass a valid integer it gives a result.

Comment: Nice story, please show use your code. mysql doesn't behave differently on different os's

Comment: how (a keyword will do ill search myself), perhaps i got something to learn

Comment: one example: table aliases are case sensitive on Unix, however are not on Windows or Mac OS X.

Comment: Your example piece of SP SQL bears no resemblance to your issue. Show the actual SP code.

Comment: Dear RiggsFolly, when I did click on execute button of my stored procedure in my routines it asks me one input (I had already declared), if I gave null it doesn't go to the procedure. But the same will run in my MAMP, without any input.  actually I have to if conditions. one is with input true and second one is with input false. why wamp doesn't satisfies the second condition.

Comment: 1. I clicked on execute        2.it asks me input.    3.input is null -> it quits            4. if input is anything  it goes through and executes the above code. :D        Input name a_id,  type BIGINT(20),  I leave the options with empty. i didn't choose unsigned, zero fill, unsigned zerofill.    Server version: 5.6.12 - MySQL Community Server (GPL),       Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.10 -        phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.0.4    Thank YOu

Comment: Still This problem is not solved. . . .  .. .. . . .

Comment: > CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_religionList`(IN
> `reqtyp` VARCHAR(10), IN `regid` BIGINT(20)) BEGIN DECLARE rList
> VARCHAR(250);  IF(reqtyp ="Admin" OR reqtyp="Staff")THEN   SET @rList
> :='SELECT religionid, religionname FROM drm_religion';  END IF;
>     IF(reqtyp ="SAdm")THEN   SET @rList :='SELECT religionid, religionname FROM drm_religion WHERE 1=1';
>         IF(regid !="" AND regid !="0")THEN
>         SET @regid = regid;
>         SET @rList := CONCAT(@rList, ' AND religionid=', @regid);
>         END IF;  END IF;
> 
> PREPARE rList FROM @rList; EXECUTE rList;

Comment: Still I don't know how to paste code here :D , IF any one edit it properly, you are welcome

Comment: IF I give reqtyp="SAdm" and regid="", it will return nothing.  reqtyp="SAdm" and regid="0" or  reqtyp="SAdm" and regid="5" Will execute correctly. Why it is not taking Null Integer input field value as input